# docker toolbox - can't mount directory using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I work on windows 10 and use docker toolbox.

When i run container using `docker run` command, i can mount local filesystem folder on container folder, like this:

```
docker run -ti --name local -p 80:80 -d -v /c/Users/name/htdocs:/app webdevops/php-apache-dev
```

But when i try to use `docker-compose up`, and make such `docker-compose.yml` file, it doesnt work - container doesnt see my local filesystem:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  server:
    image: webdevops/php-apache-dev
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /c/Users/name/htdocs:/app
```

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a small syntax issue in your `docker-compose.yml` file. If it is failing to see your local file system perhaps you're passing it a string that does not exist. I presume that `/c/Users/name/htdocs` isn't the actual absolute directory on your host. Could you please share it? Perhaps you haven't escape a non-letter character in the string?

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer.. my username actually consists of two words and i used escaping slash required in `run` command in docker-compose.yml file.

It turns out it is not required in docker-compose.yml file. It actually turned into other slash that made my `User Name` into `User/Name`.